# How to specify single disk size for Softlayer virtual server via python

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm using python softlayer to create instances of virtual servers. When I specify 2 disk sizes, the request can be verified. If I request just 1 disk size, the call fails. I don't want to use the default size. How can I specify a 100 GB drive?

Sample request:

```
vsi_request= {
    'cpus': 2,
    'memory': 6144,
    'hourly': True,
    'hostname': 'test',
    'domain': u'sample.domain.com',
    'local_disk': False,
    'datacenter': datacenter_code,
    'os_code' : u'UBUNTU_14_64',
    'dedicated': False,
    'private_vlan': 1234,
    'post_uri': 'https://bla',
    'private': True,
    'ssh_keys': [2345],
    'nic_speed': 1000,
    'tags': 'test, pleaseCancel',
    'disks': ('100')  <---- This makes it fail
}
vsi = vsmgr.verify_create_instance(**vsi_request)
```

I've tried various inputs:

```
# <no disks specification> success, default to 25 GB
#('100', '10') success
#('100') Unable to find prices for block device 0 with capacity of 1.
#('25') Unable to find prices for block device 0 with capacity of 2.
## Some invalid values just to see the error message
#('500')  Unable to find prices for block device 0 with capacity of 5.
#('100', '4') Unable to find prices for block device 2 with capacity of 4.
#('100', '0') Unable to find prices for block device 2 with capacity of 0.
```

The relevant stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
vsi = vsmgr.verify_create_instance(**vsi_request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SoftLayer\managers\vs.py", line 475, in verify_create_instance
return self.guest.generateOrderTemplate(create_options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SoftLayer\API.py", line 373, in call_handler
return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SoftLayer\API.py", line 341, in call
return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SoftLayer\API.py", line 237, in call
return self.transport(request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SoftLayer\transports.py", line 187, in __call__
raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError:  SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_NotFound): Unable to find prices for block device 0 with capacity of 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this:

```
'disks': ['100']
```

or

```
'disks': ('100',)
```

E.g:

```
vsi_request= {
    'cpus': 2,
    'memory': 6144,
    'hourly': True,
    'hostname': 'test',
    'domain': u'sample.domain.com',
    'local_disk': False,
    'datacenter': datacenter_code,
    'os_code' : u'UBUNTU_14_64',
    'dedicated': False,
    'private_vlan': 1234,
    'post_uri': 'https://bla',
    'private': True,
    'ssh_keys': [2345],
    'nic_speed': 1000,
    'tags': 'test, pleaseCancel',
    'disks': ['100']
}
```

Also, I suggest to use **get_create_options** to get available options to order a VSI:

```
mgr.get_create_options()
```